# Make disabled input stay same color like enabled

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an input field with classes:

```
.list-default .value 
{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #333333;
    float: left;
    width: 55%;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-align: right;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    padding: 12px 0px 10px;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
.list-default .value:disabled
{
    opacity:1;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000000 !important;
    float: left;
    width: 55%;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-align: right;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    padding: 12px 0px 10px;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

When I put disabled to `true` with jquery or with html the color becomes pale gray but if I put the color to for example red it is bright red.

How can I make the input text color be the same even if it's disabled?

Comment: Try using `[disabled]` in the selector instead of `:disabled`

Comment: does not work on my iphone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should set it as **readonly** rather **disabled**.

You can apply styles on it too.

**HTML:**

```
<form name="fish">
    <input type="text" name="big" value="Big Fish">
    <input type="text" name="little" value="Little Fish">
    <input type="text" name="tiny" value="Tiny Fish" readonly>
</form>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
document.forms['fish']['big'].readOnly = true;
```

**CSS:**

```
input[readonly] {
    color: #999;
}
```

Check out below fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/655Su/1/

Answer (score 1):

It's `input[disabled]` not `input:disabled`

In yout case :

```
.list-default .value[disabled]
```

Comment: i might add that is on an iphone! and nope it still does not work. The class gets added when it becomes disabled but the color changes. it seems to do this to black and greyish colors but if you put in red or green everything is ok.